# Slick slider with an overflow-y

Tags: css, overflow, slick.js

I'm using Slick Slider and I'm trying to make the overflow-y go over the next div when hovering over it, but without success (without scrolling of course).
I don't understand with the positioning and the overflow:visible  it should work right?

Is there a kind soul to help me please?
Thanks in advance

[Result on CodePen]

```html
<p class="codepen" data-height="265" data-theme-id="light" data-default-tab="html,result" data-user="1max2web" data-slug-hash="ExWjxrd" style="height: 265px; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; border: 2px solid; margin: 1em 0; padding: 1em;" data-pen-title="Slider Slick test Overflow">
  <span>See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/1max2web/pen/ExWjxrd">
  Slider Slick test Overflow</a> by Mijsoot (<a href="https://codepen.io/1max2web">@1max2web</a>)
  on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</span>
</p>
<script async src="https://cpwebassets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change the .p_test:hover state

```
overflow:visible
```

to

```
overflow-y:scroll
```

Here working: https://codepen.io/rg-the-selector/pen/vYxOXpX

Comment: sorry but it don't ... I said without a scroll ... I want the DIV came over the image ...